# What do array keys in the database definition array mean?

Tags: 7, database

I have following code in my `settings.php` file:

```
$databases['default']['default2'] = array(
  'driver'    => 'mysql',
  'database'  => 'rotary',
  'username'  => 'root',
  'password'  => 'root',
  'host'      => 'localhost',
  'prefix'    => '',
);

$databases['rotary2']['default1'] = array(
  'driver'    => 'mysql',
  'database'  => 'rotary2',
  'username'  => 'root',
  'password'  => 'root',
  'host'      => 'localhost',
  'prefix'    => '',
);
```

I know that the first keys i.e. `default` & `rotary2` are the database names.

What are the keys `default2` & `default3` for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the explanation from the `setting.php` file:

> For each database, you may optionally specify multiple "target" databases.
>   A target database allows Drupal to try to send certain queries to a different database if it can but fall back to the default connection if not. That is useful for master/slave replication, as Drupal may try to connect to a slave server when appropriate and if one is not available will simply fall back to the single master server.
>
> The general format for the $databases array is as follows:
>
> ```
> $databases['default']['default'] = $info_array;
> $databases['default']['slave'][] = $info_array;
> $databases['default']['slave'][] = $info_array;
> $databases['extra']['default'] = $info_array;
> ```
>
> In the above example, `$info_array` is an array of settings described above. The first line sets a "default" database that has one master database (the second level default). The second and third lines create an array of potential slave databases. Drupal will select one at random for a given request as needed.  The fourth line creates a new database with a name of "extra".

I hope this will give you clear idea about `default2` and `default3`.